# conan package manager: globally specify build folder

Tags: conan

By default (on Linux), conan creates a build folder under `/home/user/.conan/data/package/version/_/_/build/hash`

I'd like to use something like `/tmp/conan/package/version/hash/` as build folder.

For a single package, this is easily achieved with the `-bf` option. However, this becomes tedious when many packages are built. Is there a way to globally set the build folder to some location under `/tmp` in the configuration settings?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to separate only the build folder from data, but you can set the [Storage Path](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/config_files/conan.conf.html#storage).

If you want to discard the test package build folder too, use [CONAN_TEMP_TEST_FOLDER](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-temp-test-folder) environment variable.

The idea behind build folder is getting separated the source code from built cache. If you are developing a new recipe using `conan create` command, probably you need to do many changes in your recipe, but you don't want to download the same source for every new execution, so you reserve the source folder, and only recreate the build folder.

If you really want to remove the build folder after building a package, you can use [Hooks](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/extending/hooks.html#hooks), for instance:

```py
from conans import tools

def post_package(output, conanfile, conanfile_path, **kwargs):
    output.info("BUILD FOLDER TO BE REMOVED: %s" % conanfile.build_folder)
    tools.rmdir(conanfile.build_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll file a feature request then. It's not so much about cleanup, but more about avoiding (sometimes more, sometimes less) disk writes.

Comment: Open your feature request here: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues